# Url passing in telerik asp.net mvc panel

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, telerik, telerik-mvc

I m using Telerik Panel bar in mvc3, and i am facing a problem while passing Url??
can anyone please help me how can i pass Url in my view.

Comment: what is url. what is the problem. Your question is very vague

Comment: In panel bar at child link i want to call any action that can call my partial views from different controllers or i want to call different actions from this link.

Answer (score 1):

You need to bring controller/Action name dynamically in you model and create and pass the url

```
.Items(sub =>
              {
              for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
                 {

                  sub.Add().Text(Model.ElementAt(i).DisplayText)
                   .Url(Url.Action(Model.ElementAt(i).ActionName, Model.ElementAt(i).ControllerName, new { id = Model.ElementAt(i).IDParam }))

              }});
```

Comment: but in this case i hope the page will travel and the whole page will be refreshed. But i dont want to travel my page.

Comment: See this http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-mvc/panelbar/panelbar-item-with-url-from-ajax-action.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, I did something similiar to this using the PanelBar and Grid.In the panel bar, put a js function in the OnSelect event:

```
Html.Telerik().PanelBar()
   .Name("PanelBar")
      .ClientEvents(events =>
      {
         events.OnSelect("getEvent");
      })
      .Items(panelbar =>
      {
         panelbar.Add()
            .Text("Header Text")
            .Expanded(true)
            .Items(item =>
            {
               item.Add()
                   .Text("Test1");
               item.Add()
                   .Text("Test2");
            });
     }).Render();
```

In the getEvent function, assign a variable to each item and make an ajax post to an actionresult on your controller or something.  In my case I just made the grid rebind.

```
function getEvent(e) {
        panelItem = $(e.item).text();
        if (panelItem == "Test1") {
            var eventid1 = 1;
        }
        if (panelItem == "Test2") {
            var eventid2 = 2;
        }
        //make ajax post here or something
        $('#TheGrid').data('tGrid').rebind();
        //            $.ajax({
        //                url: '/Controller/Action',
        //                type: 'POST',
        //                data: {
        //                    eventid1: eventid1,
        //                    eventid2: eventid2,
        //                    panelItem: panelItem
        //                }
        //            });
}
```

and in your controller make a conditional statement for the eventids and perform the action you want.
Hope this helps.